# Guard with Haml, Livereload, not compiling changes

Tags: haml, guard

I've successfully installed guard with haml and livereload plugins. In a running guard shell, when both are running, if I press enter, haml successfully gets compiled to html, then served up to a listening browser.

However, when only editing the haml file, and I save a change, livereload simply reloads the browser with the same generated .html. It does not recompile .haml -> .html, then serve it to the browser.

My Guardfile is below. What am I missing in this setup? i) In the guard shell, pressing enter compiles then serves the generated html. ii) But saving changes in the haml file only serves up old html, without compiling the haml.

```
guard 'haml', :input => 'public', :output => 'public' do
  watch(%r{^public/.+\.html\.haml})
end
guard 'livereload' do
  watch(%r{.+\.(css|js|html)})
end
```

Thanks

ps - this is not a rails project. just using the raw guard, guard-haml & guard-livereload gems

Comment: Are you sure HTML file is unchanged when you save? LiveReload seems to be configured to only act on css/js/html file changes, so if the browser is reloaded when you save HAML, it would imply that HTML gets changed.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that. 1) haml is NOT getting compiled down to html, yet 2) html file is still getting served (meaning the file was touched in some way). That's the baffling thing about this.

Comment: I guess you'll be better off [reporting a ticket against guard-livereload](https://github.com/guard/guard-livereload/issues/).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I tried updating this issue earlier, but SO doesn't allow junior users to answer their own Q in under 8 hours. The issue was actually with guard-haml, and I did indeed log an issue there: https://github.com/manufaktor/guard-haml/issues/3

Answer (score 1):

With help from Thibaud ('guard' author), I got this working. Basically, I ran guard under the directory from which files are being served.

My project tree looks like "**root/public/css/etc**", and I was running guard under "**root**", and setting "**public**" as the directory to watch (guard -w public/). But I updated and moved the Guardfile to public/ , and ran guard from there. Now haml is getting compiled and served as desired.

```
guard 'haml' do
watch(/^.+\.html\.haml$/)
end
guard 'livereload' do
  watch(/^.+\.html$/)
end
```